# Pandas .loc - can I get values from more than one column with the same .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas .loc to see if elements in a list are true or not. If I input a string into my function...lets say 'Peanut_Allergy', it works just fine and returns rows where Peanut_Allergy == YES. What is the best way to search two columns? For example, I would like to input both 'Peanut_Allergy' and 
'Shellfish_Allergy' and return values that == YES for both. Can a list be used for Pandas .loc? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

import pandas as pd

```
d = {'Name':['bob', 'steve', 'bill'], 'Peanut_Allergy': ['YES', 'NO', 'YES'], 'PetHair_Allergy': ['NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 'Shellfish_Allergy': ['NO', 'Yes', 'NO']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)



def allergysearch(allergy_query):

    return (df.loc[df[allergy_query] == 'YES'])


# is there a way to use .loc on more than one column name?
print(allergysearch(['Peanut_Allergy', 'Shellfish_Allergy']))
```

Comment: The pandas [indexing, selecting, and filtering docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) have all sorts of fun ways to do this sort of querying; what have you tried? For example:`df[(df[allergy_query] == 'YES')&(df['Shellfish_Allergy']=='YES')]`

Comment: G. Anderson - very cool! I was hoping to create an input() where the user types in 'Peanut_Allergy', 'Pethair_Allergy' or whatever combination and the correct rows are returned. In my code example I tried using a list in my function call so i thought it was maybe an issue with using a list in th e.loc. So i tried converting that to a string with   listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in s])  in the function but that did not work unfortunately

Comment: That's a bit more complex, and outside the scope of you rinitial question. Given that you're trying to use user inputted lists, it sounds like you might want something more along the lines of `df.query()` or `df.filter()` from the docs. Might want to try some things, then ask another question with a more specific [mcve] for any new issue if one arises

Comment: That is a good idea. Thank you for your help

Comment: You should probably use actual boolean values, instead of `"YES"` and `"NO"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the following code:

```
df.loc[(df['Peanut_Allergy'] == 'YES') & (df['Shellfish_Allergy'] == 'YES')]
```